# DECLARE CURSOR must be the only statement in a query batch

Tags: sap-ase

I have this below script that is getting "DECLARE CURSOR must be the only statement in a query batch". May I ask what's wrong this this?

This script is saved in a file and is being executed from isql client.

```
DECLARE c1 cursor FOR
select sql_query from tempdb..M3_Checks_Query
GO

DECLARE @sql_query text

OPEN c1
FETCH c1 into @sql_query --@check_id , @sql_query, @base_table, @run_flag

WHILE @@sqlstatus = 0
BEGIN
print "test"
FETCH c1 into @sql_query
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Comment: Is there anything before your `DECLARE c1 cursor FOR` statement? Try a `go` before it.
I didn't notice any syntactical error in your code.